# Creating an array of arrays of data objects?

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a data object

I also have arrays of these data objects

I want to put these arrays of data objects into another array

```
Dim ArrayOfDataObjects1(10) as new DataObject
Dim ArrayOfDataObjects2(10) as new DataObject
Dim ArrayOfDataObjects3(10) as new DataObject

'Now, I want to put all of these into another array, how can I?
```

Thanks!

edit: I know I need to create another array with size 3, but what type do I define the array as?

Comment: Wouldn't a collection do the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not concerned with type-safety, you could use Variant. Example in Excel VBA:

```
Sub a()
Dim ArrayOfDataObjects1(10) As Worksheet
Dim ArrayOfDataObjects2(10) As Worksheet
Dim ArrayOfDataObjects3(10) As Worksheet

Dim arr(3) As Variant

Set ArrayOfDataObjects1(1) = ActiveSheet

arr(1) = ArrayOfDataObjects1

arr(2) = ArrayOfDataObjects2

arr(3) = ArrayOfDataObjects3

MsgBox arr(1)(1).Name

End Sub
```

Comment: I think using a Variant is the *only* way to do this, whether you're concerned with type safety or not.

Comment: @jtolle I think you may create a Class Module to create objects to hold those values. But never did it, so ...

Comment: Sure, I just meant that there is no VBA syntax to describe a strongly-typed array of array of dataobject...

Comment: @jtolle Ahh OK. I misunderstood you.